# The efficient way to split a String in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have some inputs like this pattern:

> org.apache.felix.dm;version="[4.1,5)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",org.osgi.service.cm;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version="[1.0,2)",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version="[1.0,2)",org.osgi.service.event;version="[1.2,2)",org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.service.metatype;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.4,2)"

And I need to split it and store it in objects or list like this:

- *Object1:*

  ```
  String name = "org.apache.felix.dm";
  String[] versions = {4.1.0, 5.0.0}
  ```
- *Object2:*

  ```
  String name = "org.osgi.framework";
  String[] versions = {1.5.0, 2.0.0}
  ```

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: answer incoming, hold on :D

Comment: @ravibagul91 actually i tried with split(" \\)\\" ") to takepart of input lik : org.apache.felix.dm;version="[4.1,5)" then i do another split(";") .. but I stopped cause seems to me wasn't the good way !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this in 3 steps

Step 1:

split the text in pairs of name and versions. so you would end up with

```
org.apache.felix.dm;version="[4.1,5)"
org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)"
org.osgi.service.cm;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version="[1.0,2)"
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version="[1.0,2)"
org.osgi.service.event;version="[1.2,2)"
org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.service.metatype;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.4,2)"
```

for this you can do the following:

```
String text = "org.apache.felix.dm;version=\"[4.1,5)\",org.osgi.framework;version=\"[1.5,2)\",org.osgi.service.cm;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.event;version=\"[1.2,2)\",org.osgi.service.log;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.metatype;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.util.tracker;version=\"[1.4,2)\"";
    String[] strArray = text.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

strArray now contains the pairs.

doing

```
for (String string : strArray) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

prints

```
org.apache.felix.dm;version="[4.1,5)"
org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)"
org.osgi.service.cm;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version="[1.0,2)"
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version="[1.0,2)"
org.osgi.service.event;version="[1.2,2)"
org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.service.metatype;version="[1.3,2)"
org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.4,2)"
```

Step 2:

create an object for every entry within the strArray and store them in a array or list (im choosing ArrayList this time, you can chosse whatever you want tho):

```
    String text = "org.apache.felix.dm;version=\"[4.1,5)\",org.osgi.framework;version=\"[1.5,2)\",org.osgi.service.cm;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.event;version=\"[1.2,2)\",org.osgi.service.log;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.metatype;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.util.tracker;version=\"[1.4,2)\"";
    String[] strArray = text.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");  
    ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : strArray) {
        String currentPair[] = string.split(";");
        list.add(new MyObject(currentPair[0], currentPair[1]
                .replaceAll("\"", "")
                .replaceAll("version=", "")
                .replaceAll("\\[", "")
                .replaceAll("\\)", "").split(",")));
    }

    for (MyObject myObject : list) {
        System.out.print("Name: " + myObject.name + " - Versions:");
        for (String version : myObject.versions) {
            System.out.print(version + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

MyObject beeing your object's class.

prints the following:

```
Name: org.apache.felix.dm - Versions:4.1 5 
Name: org.osgi.framework - Versions:1.5 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.cm - Versions:1.3 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin - Versions:1.0 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi - Versions:1.0 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.event - Versions:1.2 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.log - Versions:1.3 2 
Name: org.osgi.service.metatype - Versions:1.3 2 
Name: org.osgi.util.tracker - Versions:1.4 2
```

now this is almost what you want, only thing left ist to format the version numbers to have 3 dots.

Step 3: format version string to have 3 dots:

for that i wrote a method and put the currentpair[1]... as a parameter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "org.apache.felix.dm;version=\"[4.1,5)\",org.osgi.framework;version=\"[1.5,2)\",org.osgi.service.cm;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.event;version=\"[1.2,2)\",org.osgi.service.log;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.metatype;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.util.tracker;version=\"[1.4,2)\"";
    String[] strArray = text.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
    ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : strArray) {
        String currentPair[] = string.split(";");
        list.add(new MyObject(currentPair[0], addDots(currentPair[1]
                .replaceAll("\"", "")
                .replaceAll("version=", "")
                .replaceAll("\\[", "")
                .replaceAll("\\)", "").split(","), 3)));
    }

    for (MyObject myObject : list) {
        System.out.print("Name: " + myObject.name + " - Versions:");
        for (String version : myObject.versions) {
            System.out.print(version + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static String[] addDots(String toAdd[], int dotcount) {
    String[] formattedVersions = new String[toAdd.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> digits = new ArrayList<>();
        digits.add(toAdd[i]);
        if(toAdd[i].contains(".")) {
            digits = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(toAdd[i].split("\\.")));
        }
        for(int x = digits.size(); x < dotcount; x++) {
            digits.add("0");
        }
        String curretnFormattedVersion = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < digits.size() - 1; j++) {
            curretnFormattedVersion += digits.get(j) + ".";
        }
        curretnFormattedVersion += digits.get(dotcount - 1);
        formattedVersions[i] = curretnFormattedVersion;
    }
    return formattedVersions;
}
```

now this prints the following:

```
Name: org.apache.felix.dm - Versions: 4.1.0 5.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.framework - Versions: 1.5.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.cm - Versions: 1.3.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin - Versions: 1.0.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi - Versions: 1.0.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.event - Versions: 1.2.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.log - Versions: 1.3.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.service.metatype - Versions: 1.3.0 2.0.0 
Name: org.osgi.util.tracker - Versions: 1.4.0 2.0.0
```

which should be exactly what you need.

i cant tell wether or not this is efficient, but from the length of the code i would say no but hey, its working :D

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code, this code depends on your input string in the Question

```
package com.java;

public class Test {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    String inputString = Test.getString();

    String[] firstSplit = inputString.split("\",");
    int counter = 1;

    for (String firstString : firstSplit) {

        String[] secondSplit = firstString.split(";"); 

        for(String secondString : secondSplit) {                

            if(secondString.substring(0,1).equals("o")) {
                System.out.println("Object" + counter++);
                String name = secondString;
                System.out.println("name = " + name);
            }
            if(secondString.substring(0,7).equals("version")) {
                String[] versions = new String[2];
                versions[0] = secondString.substring(10,13) + ".0";
                versions[1] = secondString.substring(14,15) + ".0.0";
                System.out.println("Version = " + versions[0] + ", " + versions[1]);
            }

        }


    }
}


static String getString() {
    return "org.apache.felix.dm;version=\"[4.1,5)\",org.osgi.framework;version=\"[1.5,2)\",org.osgi.service.cm;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi;version=\"[1.0,2)\",org.osgi.service.event;version=\"[1.2,2)\",org.osgi.service.log;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.service.metatype;version=\"[1.3,2)\",org.osgi.util.tracker;version=\"[1.4,2)\"";
}
```

}

The Result will be

```
Object1
name = org.apache.felix.dm
Version = 4.1.0, 5.0.0
Object2
name = org.osgi.framework
Version = 1.5.0, 2.0.0
Object3
name = org.osgi.service.cm
Version = 1.3.0, 2.0.0
Object4
name = org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin
Version = 1.0.0, 2.0.0
Object5
name = org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.spi
Version = 1.0.0, 2.0.0
Object6
name = org.osgi.service.event
Version = 1.2.0, 2.0.0
Object7
name = org.osgi.service.log
Version = 1.3.0, 2.0.0
Object8
name = org.osgi.service.metatype
Version = 1.3.0, 2.0.0
Object9
name = org.osgi.util.tracker
Version = 1.4.0, 2.0.0
```